# How to create custom PowerPoint shapes / content?

Tags: powerpoint, contentpane

I want a custom Element in PowerPoint, that behaves exactly like an Image (resizing, persistence, multi occurrences) to PowerPoint.
In contrast to the Image, I want to preset a custom UIElement I write in whatever language required.

One Solution is an activeX control, but that seems to be outdated.

Is Content Pane what i am looking for? Is there any HelloWorld example out there?

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more what you're trying to do? I'm having a hard time understanding it